# coalesce.go:220: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for service.type (map[default:ClusterIP]) ---

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, flink-streaming, kubernetes-pod

How I can find which yaml file is creating this error.
I'm using Native kubernetes flink deployment, but when I run helm template, I'm getting this error.

```
coalesce.go:220: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for service.type (map[default:ClusterIP]) ---
```